# What is the reasons of water causing electronics or electrical appliances "broken"

Tags: water

We always told to keep off the electronic devices from water with no explicit reasons. Or remedies to fix the thing when accidents happened.

So, what is the physical reasons behind that submerged electronic or electrial devices get damaged?

For example speaker, motor(high-voltage). Smart phone, headphone(low voltage). Is the effect same?

Generally, is it because extremely low resistivity of water allows abnormal high current flow instead of designed current and eventually "burns" the electronic components or wires. Then there's an open circuit which disable some parts of the circuit or the whole circuit.

Apart from the problems I mentioned ,is there any chance water directly change the physical behavior of some components? If it is the cause how?

Is only my pure guess. Please point out my mistakes if they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Water can have several bad effects, not all of them directly related to electricity.

1. It can allow current to flow in directions it was never meant to flow. This can cause damage. Many devices have a wide range of different voltages in use and having higher voltages reach parts of the device that were never designed for them can do damage.
2. When current flows through water there are electrochemical affects. This can cause corrosion.
3. It can weaken or distort many materials, such as the paper typically used for speaker cones.

As far as remedies.

1. Remove power ASAP.
2. If the water was dirty, salty or otherwise contaminated then use clean water to wash it away. Dirty water is far more likely to cause problems than clean water.
3. Dry thouroughly.

Further cleaning may also help, I remember I had a beagleboard that had spent quite a bit of time wet (and unpowered). It didn't work intitally but it did work after a scrubbing the crud off with IPA.

Comment: Good call on the promoting of corrosion. I meant to include that in my response.

Answer (score 2):

Besides shorting out the components, as you mentioned, it can also be absorbed by some materials and as they try they warp and twist, potentially causing bad solder joints. 
High voltage and water do not mix because it greatly increases the chances of the operator receiving a potentially lethal electric shock. The main reason is the shorting of the components though.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for an excuse to add more photos.

The long term effects of exposure to moisture is often what kills electronics despite the product working perfectly after said exposure.

Different liquids have different effects; some destructive such as corrosion and others constructive such as the formation of conductive deposits.

Water is synonymous with rust; leave water on exposed metal and it will rust whether you like it or not. But only if the metal contains iron (or another oxidisable element, but that's not 'rust') which, of course, all IC pins and other contacts do. This corrosion, if left long enough, could cause intermittent or permanently-broken connections.

Milk:
[image: Milk!]

Tea/coffee spillage was a common sight at my previous job, along with the testament of "I haven't spilt *anything* on it, I barely use it!"

Liars, all of them. The white deposit is from the milk. It smells of off milk, which is foul, but more importantly it becomes a conductive addition. I'm not a chemist so I don't know the reason, but milk-based drinks are a real electronics killer, perhaps more so than other spills. These deposits a very stubborn and require a concerted effort to remove them. Surface mount IC packages suffer the most because it's impossible to get behind the pins to clean.

The orange deposits is the residue of *instant coffee*. Again, it's the smell that identifies it, rather than anything else. Tea leaves a different colour, typically brown. Neither are quite so conductive when dry, but I have noticed imperfections in soldered surfaces after cleaning. Perhaps some mild acidity is wreaking havoc.

Tea and coffee seem to destroy vias. From experience, you can clean all the deposits off and make it look like new but the vias will be rendered useless. This could be due to short circuits being created thus drawing too much current through the via, and so destroying it, but it has always seemed that vias outside of the 'residue zone' remain unaffected. It could be because of the acidic properties of tea and coffee - we've all heard or seen what it does to our teeth.

Coca-cola / fizzy drinks:
[image: Gunk]
When this stuff dries it leaves a horrid, sticky gunk. It doesn't do much in the way of corrosion, perhaps due to a high sugar content, which means that repairs are usually successful. The main characteristic of the gunk is that it never really dries. It stays slightly wet, therefore slightly conductive. In the above example there was a measurable resistance between the pins of SW2 and the adjacent switch, SW3. Needless to say there should have been zero conductivity between the two.

Mechanical failure is a problem with such spillages: SW3 no longer functioned properly due to the gunk. It would typically stick in the 'down' position. A tactile switch, not pictured, was jammed open due to cola infiltration.

That spillage caused irreversible damage to the plastic lens for the screen, again not pictured.

Answer (score 1):

The corrosion and warping (mechanical negative effects) are both great points.

With respect to rapid failure, you should consider the AC impedance of water. Cellphones and other devices have high-frequency clocks (Mega and Giga Hz bandwidths) and very small trace spacing so high speed data lines cannot properly communicate when water reduces dielectric constants and creates short circuits. The average cellphone battery is at 3.8V DC, which is nominal for arcing and shorts in water. DC voltage does not start sparking in dry air until a few hundred volts.

I've dropped a phone in a pool more than once and it has instantly killed the phone. I usually remove the battery and throw the whole thing in a bag of uncooked rice for 3-4 days to restore it. The raw rice acts like desiccant and sucks the moisture how of the closed environment.